# Vala Gtk css provider load_from_path

Tags: gtk, glib, vala

I don't know why `load_from_path` does not work during `sudo ninja install`. It returns:

```
warning: unhandled error `GLib.Error'
            css_provider.load_from_path ("com.github.saidbakr.quick-shutdown.css");
```

I tried to catch the exception, but the same Warning:

```
Gtk.CssProvider css_provider = new Gtk.CssProvider ();
        try {
            css_provider.load_from_path ("com.github.saidbakr.quick-shutdown.css");
        }
        catch (IOError e){
            GLib.error("", e.message);
        }
```

I checkedout the meson.build:

```
...
install_data(
    join_paths('data', meson.project_name()+ '.css'),
    install_dir: join_paths(get_option('datadir'))
)
```

The path of the file is added and it is installed to `/usr/local/share`
I don't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[The docs for Gtk.CssProvider.load_from_path()](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.CssProvider.load_from_path.html) make no mention of searching in `/usr/local/share/<app-data-dir>` or any other standard directory. It's expecting an absolute path.

The standard way to solve this is to use GResource. If you're using a tutorial or template, it probably has something on GResource that you can use.

---

If not:

- Create a file, `quick-shutdown.gresource.xml`, with the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/com/github/saidbakr/quick-shutdown">
    <file>com.github.saidbakr.quick-shutdown.css</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>
```

- Add this to your meson.build:

```
gnome = import('gnome')
resources = gnome.compile_resources('com.github.saidbakr.quick-shutdown',
  files('quick-shutdown.gresource.xml'),
)
```

- Add `resources` to the list of sources in your `executable()` call in meson.build
- Use [Gtk.CssProvider.load_from_resource()](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.CssProvider.load_from_resource.html) instead: `css_provider.load_from_resource ("/com/github/saidbakr/quick-shutdown/com.github.saidbakr.quick-shutdown.css")`
- Remove the meson code where you install the CSS file. It is now built directly into your executable.

For a real-world example of how to do this, check out the [GNOME Clocks source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-clocks/-/blob/master/data/meson.build).

This may sound like a lot of steps, but it's the same steps as adding GtkBuilder UI files (or really any other kind of static file you need in your program). If you need to do that later, all you'll have to do is add `<file>` entries to the `.gresource.xml` file.